# How can I use ASP.Net to send email through Yahoo! or Hotmail?

Tags: asp.net, email, sendmail

Is it possible to use ASP.Net to send email through Yahoo! or Hotmail? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can send it just like you would with any other mail host.  Using the SMTP client class.  It is part of the System.Net.Mail namespace.

You just need to be sure that you get all of the proper connection information.

Comment: And make sure your proxy allows SMTP connections to these servers. I've found many corporates are blocking webmail these days.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Mitchel who beat me to it.  Here's some relevant links:

IMAP settings for Yahoo, Hotmail and Gmail:
http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html

Video on using MailMessage in asp.net:
http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-416.aspx